# How Can I Make a Long Table Continue on the Next Page if it is Too Long

Tags: tables, page-breaking, tabularx, booktabs

Here is a table I created in LaTeX using tabularx and booktabs:

```
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs, enumitem}

\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize]{label=\textbullet, nosep, leftmargin=*,
                     before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}},
             after ={\end{minipage}}}

\newlist{tabenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenumerate]{label*=\arabic*.,
                       leftmargin=*,
               nosep,
               before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize},
               after=\end{minipage}}
```

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Choix de carrière: ingénieur logiciel}
\label{tab:choix-de-carriere-different}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} >{\RaggedRight}p{10em} X @{}}
\toprule
Information & Recherche \\
\midrule
Description de la carrière &
Les ingénieurs logiciels se concentrent sur l'application des principes d'ingénierie aux programmes. Chaque ingénieur logiciel écrit et valide le code des programmes d'une entreprise. Tout comme les avocats, les ingénieurs en logiciel se spécialisent dans différents domaines. Il y a le développement Web, le traitement de texte, le développement de jeux.\\
\addlinespace
Habiletés et compétences nécessaires pour cet emploi &
\begin{tabitemize} 
\item savoir le codage 
\item bien à créer la documentation 
\item savoir des langages de programmation 
\item savoir des compilateurs 
\item savoir des licences de logiciels 
\item bien au débogage  
\end{tabitemize}\\
\addlinespace
Le salaire annuel & 83 345 \$\\ 
\addlinespace
Nomme trois différents endroits pour travailler en faisant cette carrière. Par exemple, une infirmière peut travailler dans un hôpital, une clinique privée ou dans des maisons de retraites. &\\
\addlinespace
Chemin à poursuivre pour arriver à cette carrière:
\begin{tabitemize}
\item Quelle sorte de diplôme faut-il obtenir: université, collège, ou autre?
\item Faut-il aller dans une école privée ou spécialisée en formation professionnelle?
\end{tabitemize}
&
\begin{tabitemize}
\item Aller à une université n’est pas requis.
\item Un diplôme en informatique vous aidera à être embauché.
\item Les employeurs recherchent les gens qui ont un bon montant d’expérience.
\item La plupart des gens ont leurs projets logiciels sur un site Web appelé \href{https://github.com/}{GitHub}.
\begin{itemize}
\item Cela peut être utilisé pour prouver votre expérience.
\end{itemize}
\end{tabitemize}\\
\addlinespace
Programme à poursuivre:
\begin{tabitemize}
\item Quel est le nom du programme dont il faut poursuivre?
\item Quel est le nom du diplôme à obtenir?
\end{tabitemize} &
informatique\\
\addlinespace
Institutions possibles:
\begin{tabitemize}
\item Nomme trois institutions académiques qui offrent ce programme
\end{tabitemize} &
\begin{tabenumerate}
\item Université de Waterloo
\end{tabenumerate}\\
\addlinespace
Préalables:
\begin{tabitemize}
\item Quelles cours de l'école secondaire sont nécessaires pour entrer dans ce programme?
\item Quelle moyen (average) a t-on besoin d'avoir pour entrer dans le programme?
\item A t-on besoin d'un portfolio ou d'un entretien?
\item Y-a-t-il d’autres exigences ou préalables requises?
\end{tabitemize} &
\begin{tabitemize}
\item cours
\end{tabitemize}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Instead of continuing in the next page, it filled up the whole first page, including the footer. How can I fix this?

Comment: Use the `longtable` environment  or its equivalent for `tabularx`, namely the `xltabular` environment. However, note that a row cannot be broken across pages.

Comment: The `table` environment (like `figure`) is a *float*, which will never break.  A different environment is needed.  `longtable`, as suggested by @Bernard, is a good one.

Comment: The `xltabular` environment from the *xltabular* package worked perfectly. All I had to do is replace `tabularx` with `xltabular` and remove the `table` environment. Thank you @Bernard and @barbara beeton.

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad when I can help!